# gitignore vs environment variables Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, gitignore

I've been using gitignore for password/key protection on my Ruby on Rails apps, so that my config files aren't committed to and publicly available for view on Github.

Going through the Github Developer's API tutorial suggests using environment variables to store these. If I'm not deploying is there any reason I shouldn't use gitignore to store my keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no strongly compelling reason to prefer environment variables over files, but I'm not sure I'd feel comfortable relying on `.gitignore` and keeping the files in the source tree.  If you opt for files, you might want to consider moving them outside the source tree to avoid any mistakes.

If you've committed the files at any point in the past (particularly to a public site like GitHub), then adding them to `.gitignore` later isn't going to remove the copies of previous versions that were committed; they'll still be in the repository, and someone could browse back to a version where they weren't ignored.

Additionally, depending on how you run your app, having them in the same directory as the app may make you more vulnerable to web-based security holes.  If you keep them outside the app tree, you may gain some limited protection from exploits that can read arbitrary data from the app tree.  I don't know that this is all that much of a concern (an exploit that can read within the app tree can probably read outside it too), but it wouldn't hurt to keep them in another directory.

I tend to prefer environment variables because it makes deploying to Heroku easier, so I use them in development too.  I'd probably use a file for anything more than simple login/password pairs (RSA keys, etc), and store it in my home directory or somewhere under `/var/lib` or `/etc` or `/usr/local` or something.

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem designed for solving such problems specifically

Figaro: https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro

In a nutshel, Figaro provides a clean and simple way to configure your app and keep the private stuff ... private.

All of your passwords, API keys and anything confidential can be saved in a local yml and won't be pushed to remote git repo.

Comment: I will be checking this gem out. Thanks so much!